# Is every polynomial a factor of a trinomial?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

We say that $T(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a trinomial if there exist $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $T(X) = AX^n + BX^m + C$ for some $n \geq m \in \mathbb{N}$.

> Is it true that for each irreducible $g(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ there exists some
>   nonzero $h(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $g(X)h(X)$ is a trinomial?

If no, then what are some necessary/sufficient conditions on $g$ for the existence of such $h$?

Comment: All non-zero multiples of $(X-1)^k$ require at least $k+1$ non-zero coefficients. A necessary condition on $g$ is that it does not have a root $\alpha \neq 0$ of multiplicity $> 2$.

Comment: How many real zeros can a trinomial have?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov thanks! I thought about irreducible polynomials. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar a good point! It can have at most $4$ distinct real roots. So what happens if $g$ has, say, at most one real root?

Comment: What's the answer over finite fields?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser as I stated the question it is trivial that the answer is positive since an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over a field with $q$ elements divides $X^{q^n} - X$.

Comment: right, of course, sorry. here's a better question: can you bound the degree of the trinomial in the finite field case, independently of the field size?

Comment: There are a few other splitting constraints as well; e.g., a trinomial has only a bounded number of $\mathbb{Q}_p$-roots, for every fixed $p$. (Also Khovanskii's theory of fewnomials could be something worth looking up for generalizations of this kind of question.) But it would be quite interesting to show that "almost all" degree-$d$ polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (or in $\mathbb{R}[X]$) require at least $d+1$ non-zero coefficients for all their multiples.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser I suspect that such a bound does not exist, and it can be proved by counting trinomials vs polynomials.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov A random (not necessarily monic) polynomial of degree $N$ has $O(\log N)$ real roots, which gives you a growing (but not as fast as you want) bound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize some of the discussion in the comments: a trinomial can have at most four distinct real roots. A random polynomial of degree $d$ (random = all coefficients are iid, there are other models) has $\Omega(\log d)$ real roots. Which means that the probability that a random polynomial divides a trinomial goes to zero (exponentially fast with degree, though this is a little harder to prove).

Comment: Should the notation be $\Omega(\log{d})$, or $\asymp \log{d}$? With $O(\cdot)$ one could infer that only an upper bound is stated, while actually here it is the lower bound that matters.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Correct, it is actually asymptotic to constant times log.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov OK, fixed...