# Expressing every algebraic number using roots of trinomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

This question is a continuation of [Is every polynomial a factor of a trinomial?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214625/is-every-polynomial-a-factor-of-a-trinomial)

We say that $T(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a trinomial if there exist $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $T(X) = AX^n + BX^m + C$ for some $n \geq m \in \mathbb{N}$.

> Let $L$ be the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of all trinomials. Is
>   $L$ algebraically closed?